# Preferred method to install catkin on Debian stretch

Tags: catkin, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fairly new to ROS haven't looked at it in a year. This time around I was happy to see it installed via packages to Debian rather than installing a pre configured distribution .ISO, I have Debian 9 aka stretch installed on an old HP tx2000. I have ros installed by including

```
jeffa@lunar:~$ uname -a
Linux lunar 4.9.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1 (2017-03-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
jeffa@lunar:~$

root@lunar:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu stretch main
```

I followed the directions [Debian install of ROS Lunar](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian) `apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full`

Should I install catkin from packages? or build catkin from source? I tried both attempting building from source first then tried with apt-get

```
[...]
[ 19%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_surface_matching
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_video
[ 19%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 19%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_video_Release.gch
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_viz
[ 19%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 19%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61,
                 from /home/jeffa/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install/modules/viz/precomp.hpp:49:
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_v               iz_Release.gch' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3082: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 19%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_video
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'opencv3':
  Command '['/home/jeffa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j2', '-l2']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/jeffa/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3 && /home/jeffa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2

Command failed, exiting.
jeffa@lunar:~/ros_catkin_ws$
```

Then it occurred to me to `apt-get install catkin`

```
root@lunar:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@lunar:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#

root@lunar:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# dpkg --get-selections  | grep catk
python-catkin-pkg                               install
python-catkin-pkg-modules                       install
ros-lunar-catkin                                install
root@lunar:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262684/preferred-method-to-install-catkin-on-debian-stretch/) by [jhalbrecht](https://answers.ros.org/users/30535/jhalbrecht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-28**:
I'm slightly confused: you already seem to have catkin installed (afaik it's going to be installed by default if you install `ros-*-desktop-full`), and your error output seems to be about `opencv3`, not catkin.

**Comment by [jhalbrecht](https://answers.ros.org/users/30535/jhalbrecht/) on 2017-05-29**:
After a lot more reading... yup I have catkin installed. I guess the opencv came from a large number of examples ~96 saved in `~/ros_catkin_ws/src` It was the first build to encounter an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out by @gvdhoorn catkin was installed with `apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full` My bad for misunderstanding the catkin workflow.

---

Originally posted by [jhalbrecht](https://answers.ros.org/users/30535/jhalbrecht/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0